# Coloring drop shadow in a typeface

Tags: typography

I have a typeface that has a drop shadow
How can I color the shadow differently from the type after I select create outlines in illustrator
I can't seem to select just the drop shadow

Comment: Show us a picture maybe?

Comment: Hi Leslie, welcome to GDSE. If you could clarify whether this "drop shadow" is actually a part of the font itself (and let us know the specific typeface) and share some screenshots of what you have because at the minute it's not very clear. Otherwise answers here are only going to be guessing! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the letters and the shadows "melt" together into one vector shape there is no way you can select the original letters. The shapes have been combined by the author of the typeface.

I see four possible solutions:

1. You can, if you have a version of the typeface without shadows, place a copy without shadows in front of the one with shadows enabling two different colors. (VERY EASY)
2. You can manually trace the letters without shadows using pen tool and put them in front. (VERY SLOW)
3. You can manually cut the vector shapes of the letters in two using all sorts of tricks. (VERY HARD)
4. You can choose another font without the drop shadow and create your own custom one using Illustrator's effects. Hard to say exactly how when there is no screenshot. (PRETTY EASY)

Answer (score 0):

- Select your outlined text
- Open the Appearance window *(Window > Appearance or clicking its icon on the right-hand tool bar)*
- Click on Drop Shadow
  [image]
- Click on the colored square to open your Color Picker
  [image]
- Click OK
  [image]